# Send data back to client with UDP using Apache Mina

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, udpclient, apache-mina

I am using Apache Mina to create a server to accept UDP Client requests. I have read the Official documentation provided by Apache Mina regarding [UDP Server & UDP Client](http://mina.apache.org/udp-tutorial.html). However, I wished to know when the server receives a message, can I write back to the UDP Client using the same session(I know UDP is connectionless at Network Layer, however I can get the IP and PORT of the remote host at Application Layer) such that UDP Client receives a message. I know this is possible is TCP but am a little confused about UDP. I know this may not exactly be Java based but more Network Layer based question. Would appreciate if somebody could clear this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to the same and thought i  would share.

UDP is connectionless however I can use the same session which I have in Apache Mina to write to the session. I tried it as a sample also and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {

            for (int i = 0; i < session.getService().getManagedSessions().values().toArray().length; i++) {

                IoSession aSession=(IoSession) session.getService().getManagedSessions().values().toArray()[i];
                aSession.write("Any Message");
            }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this your handler class

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {
        // response every time get data 
        byte[] b = "Received".getBytes();
        final IoBuffer responsebuffer = IoBuffer.allocate(b.length);
        responsebuffer.put(b);
        responsebuffer.flip();
        session.write(responsebuffer);
        SocketAddress remoteAddress = session.getRemoteAddress();

        if (message instanceof IoBuffer) {
            IoBuffer buffer = (IoBuffer) message;
            final CharsetDecoder decoder = getCharsetDecoder(session);
            String receivedMsg = buffer.getString(decoder);
            String data = remoteAddress + " Received: " + receivedMsg;
            server.append(data);
        }

    }
```